# Why does my curved animation begin the animation from another location?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a curved motion animation that starts at the imageview location and ends 150 pixels above it.

Here is a drawing that shows what I want to achieve VS what actually happens:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
myAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,1);
        myAnimator.setDuration(2500);
        myAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
                        .floatValue();
                tickImg.setTranslationX((float) (100 *Math.sin(value*Math.PI)));
                tickImg.setTranslationY((float) (100 *Math.cos(value*Math.PI)));
            }
        });
```

I want to animation to work like in the green path, and not like in the red path. Sorry if this is a newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to start the animation out at a translation (x,y) of (0,0). Consider what happens when value = 0:

`100 *Math.sin(0*Math.PI)` == 0

`100 *Math.cos(0*Math.PI)` == 100

We want the second expression to equal 0, not 100! To fix, change it to this:

`100 *Math.cos(0*Math.PI) - 100` == 0

We are simply offsetting the animation you already have by 100 pixels in the vertical direction.